# Glassware with listed command is not visible in menu after upgrade to XE16

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

My app is using the "play a game" command to be started by voice command and be visible in the Google Glass menu.

After upgrading to XE16 it disappeared from the menu and I could not find any upgrade notes for developers to make it work.

What changes needs to be made for the voice start command to work on the upgraded glass version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrade to XE16 the following changes must be made for voice activation and enlisting in menu.

**Listed voice commands:**

*Listed* commands are commands available by default and they can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command).

The triggering XML should be changed from:
`<trigger keyword="@string/play_a_game" />`
to:
`<trigger command="PLAY_A_GAME" />`

**Unlisted voice commands:**

*Unlisted* commands are for development purposes only and you will have to submit your command for approval.

You don't have to change your triggering XML file, but you will have to add the following permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
```

More info about starting glassware: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware